# delete and update method not working in not django rest framework

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to build an API using DRF, get() and post() method is working fine but the delete and update methods are not working.
I am getting this error:

> TypeError: delete() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk'

views.py file

```
class MenuList(APIView):

def get(self, request):
    menu = Menu.objects.all()
    serializer = MenuSerializer(menu, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def post(self, request):
    serializer = MenuSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

def delete(self, request, pk):
    menu = self.get_object(pk)
    menu.delete()
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

class MenuDetail(APIView):

""" Retrieve, update or delete a Menu instance."""

def get_object(self,pk):
    try:
        return Menu.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Menu.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

def get(self, request,pk):
    menu = self.get_object(pk)
    menu = MenuSerializer(menu)
    return Response(menu.data)

def put(self, request, pk):
    menu = self.get_object(pk)
    serializer = MenuSerializer(menu, data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_404_BAD_REQUEST)

def delete(self, request, pk):
    menu = self.get_object(pk)
    menu.delete()
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

class MenuItemList(APIView):

def get(self, request):
    menuitem = MenuItem.objects.all()
    serializer = MenuItemSerializer(menuitem,  many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def post(self, request):
    serializer = MenuItemSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

def delete(self, request, pk):
    menuitem = self.get_object(pk)
    menuitem.delete()
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

class MenuItemDetail(APIView):

def get_object(self,pk):
    try:
        return MenuItem.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except MenuItem.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

def get(self, request, pk):
    menuitem = self.get_object(pk)
    menuitem = MenuItemSerializer(menuitem)
    return Response(menuitem.data)

def put(self, request, pk):
    menuitem = self.get_object(pk)
    serializer = MenuItemSerializer(menuitem, data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_404_BAD_REQUEST)

def delete(self, request, pk):
    menuitem = self.get_object(pk)
    menuitem.delete()
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

models.py file

```
class Menu(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
chef = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
available = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__(self):
    return '{} {} {}' .format(self.name, self.chef.first_name, 
                              self.chef.last_name)

class MenuItem(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
cost_to_make = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)
sale_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)
available = models.BooleanField(default=False)
menu = models.ForeignKey(Menu, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

url.py file

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^Menu/', views.MenuList.as_view()),
url(r'^Menu/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.MenuDetail.as_view()),
url(r'^MenuItem/',views.MenuItemList.as_view()),
url(r'^MenuItem/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.MenuItemDetail.as_view()),]
```

Comment: You code seems to correct. Can you confirm `runserver` is restarted after code change?.

Comment: Also make sure correct rest request methods is used from client side.
for example for delete use `DELETE` for partial update use `PATCH` for Full update use `PUT`.

Comment: the server is started and running fine but when I am trying to delete any object the error comes.

Comment: which request method is passed from client slide? (is it post? is it delete ?)

Comment: post is running fine but delete shows error

Comment: its a tutorial based project and running on my local server

Comment: Generally a full Trackback is helpful, in case errors are thrown

Answer (score 0):

Your `urls.py` doesn't have a `pk` argument for `MenuList` nor for `MenuItemList`.

So when you don't supply a pk in your request there is no way for one to be received in your code.

But the way you implemented the DELETE methods in your Lists also seems like you actually want to delete an Object, wich is done at the respective detail views (and you already implement it there too).

You might also want to use [DRF's Generic views](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/), that automatically take care of most of the things you do in your code.